# Debugging a Service Fabric Application on a locally hosted cluster (different machine than mine)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to debug a service fabric application hosted on a different machine than mine? And if so, how?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application

Following this I can only debug locally or in the cloud. I tried adding the cluster to my local service fabric, but I can't seem to find the option..

Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: I know I can host it locally, and we do so during development. But we also have a staging cluster hosted on our local server. And it happens that we have different results. Probably because of it being hosted on 3 VM's and running 3 nodes while local cluster is running on one machine. And debugging on the live server in azure is just... wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our Visual Studio Service Fabric tools support debugging against a local dev cluster and remote debugging against Azure clusters using Cloud Explorer to configure and attach. We don't support debugging against a on-prem cluster that is not a local dev cluster.

We DO support publishing to a on-prem cluster!

Comment: We realise we can publish to it, since we're already using it as a Test-Cluster. Will this ever be possible or is it on the roadmap?

Comment: No, it is not currently on the roadmap.

Comment: so how do we debug a remote cluster?